# warning BC40056: Namespace or type specified in the Imports 'MS.Internal.Xaml.Builtins' doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found

Tags: wpf, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I have a WPF VB.NET project in Visual Studio 2008. For some reason, Visual Studio thinks that it needs to add an

```
Imports MS.Internal.Xaml.Builtins
```

to every auto-generated XAML partial class (= the `nameOfXamlFile.g.vb` files), resulting in the following warning:

> warning BC40056: Namespace or type specified in the Imports 'MS.Internal.Xaml.Builtins' doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found. Make sure the namespace or the type is defined and contains at least one public member. Make sure the imported element name doesn't use any aliases.

I can remove the `Imports` line, but, since this is an auto-generated file, it reappears every time that the project is rebuilt.

This warning message is annoying and clutters my error list. Is ther something that can be done about it? Or is it a known bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently ran into this bug myself in one of my WPF projects.  I compared references to a project that didn't have these problems and found that my project that was having the problem had these libraries referenced:

```
Microsoft.Windows.Design
Microsoft.Windows.Design.Extensibility
Microsoft.Windows.Design.Interaction
Microsoft.Windows.Design.Markup
```

I deleted these references and sure enough, the warnings went away.

Comment: I did the same thing to get around the same error.  One note is that the project in question was converted from VS2008 to VS2010.  I suspect something in the conversion screwed up.